# connect with facebook login in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, fbconnect, facebook-login

I want to use 3rd party authentication(facebook) to logged-in my web application. I'm searching on google getting this type of code, most of users said it's working but not working for me.
I use following code.

1. ConnectAuthentication class

   ```
   public class ConnectAuthentication
   {

   public static bool isConnected()
   {
       return (SessionKey != null && UserID != -1);
   }
   public static string ApiKey
   {
       get { return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationKey"]; }
   }
   public static string SecretKey
   {
       get { return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SecretKey"]; }
   }
   public static string SessionKey
   {
       get { return GetFacebookCookie("session_key"); }
   }
   public static int UserID
   {
       get
       {
           int userID = -1;
           int.TryParse(GetFacebookCookie("user"), out userID);
           return userID;
       }
   }
   private static string GetFacebookCookie(string cookieName)
   {
       string retString = null;
       string fullCookie = ApiKey +"_" + cookieName;
       if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[fullCookie] != null)
           retString = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[fullCookie].Value;
       return retString;
   }
   ```

   }
2. FBLogin.js

```
    function CallFB() {
        FB.ensureInit(function () { FB.XFBML.Host.parseDomTree(); });
        FB.init("203596266327066", "http://localhost:61283/xd_receiver.htm");
    }

    function FBLogOut() {
        FB.ensureInit(function () { FB.XFBML.Host.parseDomTree(); });
        FB.init("203596266327066", "http://localhost:61283/xd_receiver.htm");
        if (FB.Connect != null)
            FB.Connect.logout();
    }
```

1. Default.aspx - start page

   ```
   <script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php"
       type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/fblogin.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
           CallFB();
       });        
   </script>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div>
       <br />
       <div id="facebk" style="height: 5px;">
           <fb:login-button length='long' onlogin='window.location.reload()' size='medium'>
           </fb:login-button>
       </div>
   </div>
   </form>
   ```

3.Default.aspx.cs

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        if (ConnectAuthentication.isConnected())
            Response.Redirect("AuthUser.aspx");
    }
```

1. AuthUser.aspx - access only authenticated user

   $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#btn").click(function () {
                   FBLogOut();
           });
       });

Comment: it always get ConnectAuthentication.isConnected() to false & actually i'm connected to FaceBook on login click